# Unable to compile a proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have created a proto file in my project named allinone.proto. I wanted to create a service using grpc in which I can call as a client. Following the tutorial in this [link](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html),
I am trying to run the command in my projects directory to compile the proto file I just created

`$ python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/all_in_one.proto`

The code for the proto file is

```
syntax = "proto3"

message ImageRGB {
    bytes content = 1;
}

message BoudingBox {
    int32 x = 1;
    int32 y = 2;
    int32 w = 3;
    int32 h = 4;
}

message Point2D {
    int32 x = 1;
    int32 y = 2;
}

message FaceDetections {
    repeated BoundingBox face_bbox = 1;
}

message FaceLandmarks {
    string landmark_model = 1;
    repeated Point2D point = 2;
}

message FaceLandmarkDescriptions {
    string landmark_model = 1;
    repeated string landmark_description = 2;
    repeated Point2D landmark_avg = 3;
}

message FaceLandmarkModels {
    repeated FaceLandmarkDescriptions model = 1;
}

}
```

I am getting an error doing so

```
$python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/all_in_one.proto
~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/: warning: directory does not exist.
/home/samuel/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/all_in_one.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

Can anyone help me figure why the error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not allowed to reply by comments.

I guess when you set the proto_path(-I), you can use the relative path based on it.
Can you please try something like this?
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I~/projects/All-In-One/models/grpc/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. all_in_one.proto

Comment: I tried to run the command but I got the following error `~/projects/All-In_one/models/grpc/: warning: directory does not exist.
all_in_one.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses thisfile.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).`

Comment: Probably protoc doesn't recognize '~' with the -I flag, can you please try use the absolute path or relative path start with './'?

Comment: I managed to resolve the error but I got another error saying `all_in_one.proto:4:38: Expected ")".` I added a service definition after  `syntax = "proto3";

service AllInOne {
 rpc AllInOne(AllInOneRequest returns AllInOneResponse){}
}` I couldn't know where that ')' must be put.

Comment: I can see a few errors in your proto file:
1. missing ';' in the first line.
2. extra '}' in the last line.
3. BoudingBox typo.
I guess fixing them will generate the correct files.

Comment: yes Got it fixed and generated the correct all_in_one_pb2_grpc.py and all_in_one_pb2.py files thank you and I appreciate your help @ddyihai